# Combining Panel Objects in Canoe VTS

Tags: xml, panel, can-bus, canoe

I am new to Capal and searching for a way to include common objects in two different Panel. For example i have two Panels with some same objects and i want to include these object in both Panels (with header file maybe ,if such a thing is possible in Canoe.) ,so that any  Design changes made in Object changes the Object in both Panels automatically and i dont have to do it manually.
If someone knows if it's possible  or can help me with code structure, it would be a great help. Thanks  !!